# Trailing return type in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

With the introduction of `auto` return type in C++14, is there any real situation that trailing return type is required or it's completely obsolete in C++14 and 17?

Comment: Apart from what's been mentioned already, trailing return-type also permits you to use `this` in return-types.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider...

```
auto f(int x)
{
    if (x == 2)
        return 3;
    return 2.1;
}
```

...this has an ambiguous return type - `int` or `double`.  An explicit return type - whether prefixed or trailing - can disambiguate it and casts the `return` argument to the return type.

Trailing return types specifically are also useful if you want to use `decltype`, `sizeof` etc on some arguments:

```
auto f(int x) -> decltype(g(x))
{
    if (x == 2)
        return g(x);
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: @Tony D: would you please edit your answer and make it clearer. I did not get your point and and I could not apply your example.

Comment: @Shadi: can you explain what you didn't understand?  Can you see the two return statements in the first function have arguments of different type, so automatic deduction will fail?  In the second example the return type is `decltype(g(x))`, which means `f(int)` should return whatever type `g(int)` returns.  Google for `decltype` documentation if you're unfamiliar with it.  My point there is that you can't use the older leading return type a la `decltype(g(x)) f (int x) { ... }` because `x` isn't declared before the compiler sees `g(x)` - it can only be used after `int x`.

Comment: @Tony D: Thank you, it is clear now. However, I still do not understand how can we use `sizeof`in trailing return type.

Comment: @Shadi: for example, `auto f(int x) -> std::array<bool, sizeof x> {...}`

Comment: Won't `decltype(g(x))` be the same as `decltype(g(0))`?

Comment: @user202729: yes, but using `g(x)` has maintenance related advantages - if you change the type of the `x` parameter it remains correct, there's no arbitrary "magic" constant, and it matches the "return" statement so it's more obvious why it's used.

Answer (score 14):

Trailing return type gives you SFINAE support.  Deduced return types never cause an error early enough to be a mere substitution failure.

This permits compilers not to have to be able to compile entire arbitrary functions bodies and then back out cleanly in order to determine if an overload applies.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from where you are required to use it (and the other answers here give great examples), you can use it for **clarity**, for explicitly stating what the function returns. This is very important once you realize (hopefully pretty soon) that reading a code is at least as important as writing it.

consider:

```
auto split(gsl::cstring_span str)
{
    ...
    ...
    auto tokens = std::vector<gsl::cstring_span>();
    ...
    ...
    for (...) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    return tokens;
}
```

versus:

```
auto split(gsl::cstring_span str) -> std::vector<gsl::cstring_span>();
{
   ... doesn't even matter
}
```

I shouldn't be looking in the implementation to see what the contract of the function is. I could probably guess what the return type is by looking at the first example, but these kind of assumptions are dangerous in programming. I would have to scan the implementation to be sure of what I receive when I call the function. With the second example, I have the interface cleanly stated. I don't care of the implementation, as the name is self-explanatory and so I don't have to look in the definition at all.

Further more consider this even worst example. Lets find out what this function returns:

```
auto split(const char* str)
{
   return split(gsl::cstring_span(str));
}
```

Ok, now search for that overload:

```
auto split(gsl::cstring_span str)
{
   return split_impl(str);
}
```

Okey..., now lets follow that:

```
auto split_impl(gsl::cstring_span str)
{
   return split_impl(str, ::isspace);
}
```

Are you f** kidding me.

So I hope you see the point.

I am not saying always use explicit return type, I am saying consider that knowing the return type should be quickly with a simple glance at the function. Sometimes, for one-liners, that can be discovered from the body. Sometimes, it can be safely guessed from the name (e.g. `is_empty()` clearly returns `bool`). Other times, you would need to explicitly name it. Make the developer's life who uses your code later simpler, especially since that one will eventually inevitably be you.